# How do I disable the Notes App on ipads?

Tags: ipad, applications, notes.app

My students are using the Ipad Notes app to pass notes in class.  Some are not appropriate either.  Is there a way to disable the Notes app on an ipad?

Comment: Disable one thing, and they will find another.   On a serious note your schools IT should be able to do this.... unless you have a very small school that just bought some iPads and are not part of Apple's Apple and Education.

Comment: To expand on what @Tyson said, I'm pretty sure the Apple for Education program gives you a large amount of control over what can and cannot be done on the device. Unfortunately, technology is technology and humans are smart; your students can and most likely will find another way to circumvent any efforts related to this.

Comment: Why are they permitted to use them during the class?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable the Notes app in iOS devices, either with Restrictions or with Apple Configurator. There is no way I know of to delete or hide any of the pre-installed Apple apps, either.

You **can** lock each iPad to a single app using guided access, [described here](http://www.howtogeek.com/177366/how-to-lock-down-your-ipad-or-iphone-for-kids/).

Your best mechanism for preventing this behavior is through social engineering: a clearly written Acceptable Use Policy signed off by by parent & student; and trips to the principal's office, with penalties for infractions.